# Any known issues with DELETE-statement in Java's MySQL-Connector?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have checked around, and I have checked up the issue all over Google, tried all kind of solutions, but I haven't found any solution.
The issue is that the `DELETE`-statement isn't really working.

```
java.sql.Connection conn = new Connection().getConnection();

try {
    conn = new Connection().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM _users WHERE _id = ?");

    statement.setInt(1, 4);
    statement.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
} finally {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using, and for all I have understood `statement.executeUpdate()` is the method to use. I have also tried `statement.execute()` and all kinds of tries.
There is no exception, so no known error. The new Connection().getConnection() gives away an valid connection ( working with `SELECT`,`INSERT`,`UPDATE` ) and the user has permissions for `SELECT`,`INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE`.
I am currently using technology such as:

- Java 6 (1.6)
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
  and I also had the same experience with
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.19.jar

So I would highly appreciate if anyone had the same problem as I seem to have, what it might be because of and/or how to fix it.
Thank you everyone at Stackoverflow. :) Hope this been relevant to anyone else.

Comment: Doesn't delete. That is the thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that something `isn't really working` does not give us much to go on.

But I suggest that you read up on Transactions.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Unless `autoCommit` is turned on, you will need to `commit` your transaction.

Also in your example, you use the ID with the value of `4` - does this really exist?

Comment: Thank you for the help.
The ID 4 did exist but did nothing. My connection automaticely had `conn.setAutoCommit(false)` and when I set it to `conn.setAutoCommit(true)` and then add an `conn.commit()` in the end , then it worked.<br/><br/>
I still don't really get why though, so I'm gonna re-read-up on transactions and try to figure out why it would work ( everything else works ).<br/>
Thank you once again.

Comment: @JohnCastell You either call `commit()` or enable auto-commit, you shouldn't do both.

Answer (score 0):

You always use the same id to delete from. So whether id 4 exists or not the statement will always execute.

Answer (score 0):

Does the id 4 exist? You can issue this command over and over in mysql: `DELETE FROM _users WHERE _id = 4;`

So long as the table _users exists, you won't get any error. It'll just keep running. Verify that id 4 exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved! **So this answer is for future needs**
My connection is set automaticely to `conn.setAutoCommit(false)` and this works for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `SELECT`, and for the `DELETE-statement` to work is to set connection to `conn.setAutoCommit(true)`, and then add an `conn.commit()` to make the statement to go through.
Want to thank [user2310289](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/user2310289) for s/he's answer which helped alot.

Comment: You either call `commit()` or enable auto-commit, you shouldn't do both.

Comment: Yes, noticed that now.